# Polymorphism in quering MongoDB using MongoDB.Bson in c#

Tags: .net, mongodb, serialization, polymorphism

I have collection in mongo DB which contains few types of documents.
All of the documents contain base common properties and some extra.
In C# it represent as Polymorphism:

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Cat), typeof(Dog))]
public class Animal
{
    public int Code;
}

[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Lion), typeof(Tiger))]
public class Cat : Animal
{
    public string CatProperty;
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
}

public class Lion : Cat
{
}

public class Tiger : Cat
{
}
```

My question is : How should I implement "getAnimalByCode" when I don't know before what is the exact type of the Animal which is going to returned. I emphasize that I want to get the entire document, not only the common properties of Animal...

I saw this toturial but I don't manage to select like this:

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<Animal>("collectionName");
var myAnimal = collection.Find(animal => animal.Code == 5).FisrOrDefault();
```

Document with code 5 has CatProperty and the seriliazation failed.

Comment: Can you share the document and the exception that you get on de-serialization? I suspect that the driver does not know which class to use.

Comment: The documents are like this:
{Code : 7}, {Code: 5, CatProperty : "miauu" }
The exception is :
 system.FormatException: Element 'CatProperty ' does not match any field or property of class Animal. at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeClass(BsonDeserializationContext context) @Markus

Comment: Is there no `_t` property on the documents? Do you need to map the `Code` to the classes?

Comment: @Markus, who should insert the _t to the document? Is it my responsibility (the insertion function has to refer to this?) or it's automatically inserted by the driver? Now I don't have the _t in my documents, BUT the documents where inserted to the collection before I have added [BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Cat), typeof(Dog))] to the classes.
Do you think it should cause a problem?

Comment: The driver automatically inserts the `_t`, but if you added the `BsonKnownTypes` afterwards, the driver could not know. Try to add `_t` with a value of `Cat` to the document with `CatProperty` and try again to read this one document.

Comment: Thank you very much. @Markus
This was my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documents you provided in the comments lack the *type discriminator*. This is a property that the MongoDB C# Driver uses to determine the type of document upon deserialization in cases when polymorphism is used. By default, this property is named `_t`.

The reason for the missing property is that you made the MongoDB C# Driver aware of the polymorphism and the types that can encountered in a collection with the `BsonKnownTypes` attribute after the documents had been stored for the first time.

By default, the name of the type is stored in the type discriminator, e.g. `Cat`. If you add the `_t` field to the documents so that it matches the expected type of a document, you will be able to deserialize the documents to their original type in the inheritance hierarchy.

For more information on polymorphism for MongoDB documents see this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/serialization/polymorphic-objects/) in the docs.